# How do I remove partially duplicated information within a variable, but duplicated between fields

Tags: r, duplicates

```r
House_Number<-c("11", "14 Jas", "24 Baker Street", "38 Home Close", "Flat 6, 85", "Flat 9", "38 Hightower Close BG6 7HU")
Street<-c("Pascale Street", "Jasmine Court", "24 Baker Street", "Home Close", "85 The Strand", "28 Lake Close", "38 Hightower Close BG6 7HU")
Postcode<-c("AB1 2BY", "AC2 3DF", "DF4 5TH", "FG4 8TG", "CF5 6YH", "DH7 8UJ", "38 Hightower Close BG6 7HU")
(df<-as.data.frame(cbind(House_Number,Street,Postcode)))
```

I have address data in multiple fields; House_Number, Street, Postcode and in some of these fields there are either fully or partially duplicated information.

I plan to concatenate these fields together to make a one line address. However, the duplicated information would mean that I end up with incorrect addresses.

Therefore, I need to remove the duplicated information from one of the fields it appears in. It would be best if the information stayed complete in the Street field I think (so keep street name complete in the Street field, rather than removing that and having it in the House_Number field), but that is purely preference and shouldn't make a huge difference. How might I accomplish this?

The dataframe should look like this afterwards ideally:

```r
House_Number<-c("11", "14 ", "", "38", "Flat 6, ", "Flat 9", "")
Street<-c("Pascale Street", "Jasmine Court", "24 Baker Street", "Home Close", "85 The Strand", "28 Lake Close", "38 Hightower Close BG6 7HU")
Postcode<-c("AB1 2BY", "AC2 3DF", "DF4 5TH", "FG4 8TG", "CF5 6YH", "DH7 8UJ", "")
(df_correct<-as.data.frame(cbind(House_Number,Street,Postcode)))
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Edited to add an additional error type that I found where the entire address was in all three fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Because of things like `Jas` this is a lot harder.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_split(.x, " "))) %>%
  mutate(
    House_Number = map2(House_Number, Street, function(x,y) x[!map_lgl(x, ~any(str_detect(y, .x)))]),
    Postcode = map2(Postcode, Street, function(x,y) x[!map_lgl(x, ~any(str_detect(y, .x)))])
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~map_chr(.x, ~str_c(.x, collapse = " "))))
```

gives:

```
  House_Number                     Street Postcode
1           11             Pascale Street  AB1 2BY
2           14              Jasmine Court  AC2 3DF
3                         24 Baker Street  DF4 5TH
4           38                 Home Close  FG4 8TG
5      Flat 6,              85 The Strand  CF5 6YH
6       Flat 9              28 Lake Close  DH7 8UJ
7              38 Hightower Close BG6 7HU
```

Note that this wont work if there are typing errors or on lower/upper cases. Also this might remove sometimes something that you don't want to be removed, really depends on use cases.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am getting an error as follows when I try to run it:  Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Result 3 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 0
i Input `..1` is `across(everything(), ~map_chr(.x, ~str_c(.x, collapse = " ")))`.